# Moving mouse and keep .mouseenter function

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseenter, mouseleave

This is my first time creating something with jQuery, so I am really excited. I did this small thing where you can hover on artists names and see the concerts available.

Really proud of myself, but I'd like now to be able to move my cursor to the dates (and maybe later I'll create a link for them), but if I move the mouse outside of the big square, then .mouseleave activates and baaam, it's gone.

How should I do this?

Here's the code (the hover is not working, I don't understand why :()

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    

    $('show').hide();
    $('.alldates').hide();
    
    $('.band').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
        $(this).next().show(200);
    });
    
    $('.band').mouseleave(function() {
        
        $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.5);
        $(this).next().hide(200);
    });
   
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}

ul,li {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
}



.band {
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:center;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: white;
}

.band p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

show {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.alldates {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 120px;
}

.date {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: solid 1px #95989A;
    height: 52px;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color:#95989A;
}

.band1 {
    background-color: rgba(40,177,227,1);
}

.band2 {
    background-color: rgba(227,40,52,1);
}

.band3 {
    background-color: rgba(227,213,40,1);
}

.band4 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.band5 {
    background-color: rgba(171,40,227,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    
<div class="info">
    <div class="band band1">
    <p>All Time Low</p>
        <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>
    <div class="alldates">
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
        </div>
        
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="info">
    <div class="band band2">
    <p>Johnny Cash</p>
        <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>
    <div class="alldates">
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
        </div>
        
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="info">
    <div class="band band3">
    <p>30 Seconds to Mars</p>
        <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>
    <div class="alldates">
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
        </div>
        
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="info">
    <div class="band band4">
    <p>Never Shout Never</p>
        <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>
    <div class="alldates">
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
        </div>
        
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="info">
    <div class="band band5">
    <p>Miley Cyrus</p>
        <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>
    <div class="alldates">
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
        </div>
        
        <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    

    
    
    
</div>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The code snippet seems to be working, unless I'm misunderstanding the expected behavior.

Comment: @Goose I think he means that when you hover over the expanded dropdown-menu to select something, the dropdown disappears again because `mouseleave` is triggered for the big square that activated the dropdown in the first place

Comment: **Answer:** I think you could make the dates dropdown a child of the big square, that way, when you hover the dropdown you're still technicallyhovering the big square and the dropdown won't collapse until you move out of the whole thing (square and dropdown).

Comment: Oops, it is working on the snippet! My mistake then!

YES! That makes total sense! And it's really simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the selector to `.info` so `mouseenter` is triggered on the parent element that wraps both of your elements. Then use `$.find()` to toggle the state of the children of the `.info` you're hovering.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('show').hide();
    $('.alldates').hide();
    
    $('.info').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('.band').fadeTo('fast',1);
        $(this).find('.alldates').show(200);
    });
    
    $('.info').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('.band').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
        $(this).find('.alldates').hide(200);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul,li {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.band {
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:center;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: white;
}

.band p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

show {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.alldates {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 120px;
}

.date {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: solid 1px #95989A;
    height: 52px;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color:#95989A;
}

.band1 {background-color: rgba(40,177,227,1);}
.band2 {background-color: rgba(227,40,52,1);}
.band3 {background-color: rgba(227,213,40,1);}
.band4 {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);}
.band5 {background-color: rgba(171,40,227,1);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="info">
    <div class="band band1">
      <p>All Time Low</p>
      <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>
    
    <div class="alldates">
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
      </div>
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="info">
    <div class="band band2">
      <p>Johnny Cash</p>
      <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>
    
    <div class="alldates">
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
      </div>
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="info">
    <div class="band band3">
      <p>30 Seconds to Mars</p>
      <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>
    
    <div class="alldates">
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
      </div>
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="info">
    <div class="band band4">
      <p>Never Shout Never</p>
      <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>
    
    <div class="alldates">
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
      </div>
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="info">
    <div class="band band5">
      <p>Miley Cyrus</p>
      <show>Show dates</show>
    </div>

    <div class="alldates">
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">30 Oct 2017</li>
        <li id="place">London</li>
      </div>
      <div class="date">
        <li id="time">2 Nov 2017</li>
        <li id="place">Paris</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I approve both these messages :P